# Retrieve key for a given value in an NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary, key-value

I'm trying to avoid creating multiple dictionaries, one where the key is the value, and another where the value is the key.

So I can easily look for a value if I have the key by doing

```
[self.myDic objectForKey: word];
```

But is there a way to go through the values and see if it matches `word`, and if it does, then give me the key? Or do I have to iterate through the whole thing?

Comment: Please scan the relevant documentation before asking such a question. A few seconds looking at the `NSDictionary` docs would have revealed the answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I do  not want to iterate through the whole dictionary, that's what the whole point of the question. I want to match the value, not the key.

Comment: Exactly, see the answer by bbarnhart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the keys matching the value with `allKeysForObject`.  Your dictionary could have more than one key for the same object.

Comment: Good one. Never noticed that method.

Answer (score 1):

you can get all the keys with `yourDict.allKeys` and iterate them until you find the right object .

```
   for (NSString* key in yourDict.allKeys) {
        if([yourDict objectForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"somethinghere object/other equalitu"){
            return key;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the hard way.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to iterate through the whole thing, and see if there's an existing method that does it for me.

Comment: other way is to use an opposite dictionary.